# Movie about a family with an illegal 3rd child on a planet people are trying to escape

Tags: story-identification, movie

- Movie was definitely released before 2016.
- it is about a family with 3 kids for some reason it is illegal to have more than 2 kids. I think the reason is that the planet is in very poor condition air quality is very bad and at the brink of being uninhabitable.
- The youngest(around 9 yrs old) gets caught by the authorities and the father is jailed.
- everyone on the planet is trying to escape/move to a parallel universe/another planet/time traveled back through some big blue teleportation gate. It doesn’t look like a chaos situation but more like a government approved move.
- The mom helps the husband who is in jail which is basically unmanned and tiny by giving him a small object the size of a pen which is actually a laser which can cut through metal.
- The husband escapes goes somewhere grabs a bag and seems to be wearing normal clothes and makes a run for the portal. His family is already on the other side except for his youngest daughter she was inside the bag. There are some military personnel upon arrival the husband collapses and looks disoriented the mom is screaming don’t shoot. The military finds the kid inside the bag. They understand he is not a threat and his actions were made because of a desperate situation.
- The military lets it go provides the family with a home seems like they have already established a colony/settlement of sort and gives the husband a job because he was ex-cop/military before getting captured for having 3 kids.
- The colony is protected by a big fence I think because there are dinosaurs here. Predators like t-Rex.
- I remember the eldest son and the middle daughter stole a jeep or something to sneak out with some friends they made at the colony/settlement.
- Additional information:
- The eldest son had a transparent blue phone he used to text someone attached to his forearm(future tech)
- The teleportation gate was huge and blue
- the atmosphere/environment was very dark/bleak before the teleportation
- Almost everyone wore dark clothes before teleportation
- The planet/place was very tropical and people wore somewhat normal clothes
- And all the houses looked kinda the same like they were military issued but they were light coloured (not sure)
- The new planet is basically untouched in the sense that there is no technology apart from what they brought from the gate.

This is everything I can remember. I have been trying to find it for 6 years.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Where did you see this? What language was it in?  Was it live-action or animated?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may have seen the pilot episode of [Terra Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_Nova_(TV_series)) from 2011.

> Terra Nova is an American science fiction drama television series. It
> aired on the Fox Network for one season from September 26 to December
> 19, 2011. The series documents the Shannon family's experiences as
> they establish themselves as members of a colony, set up 85 million
> years in the Earth's past, fleeing the dystopian overpopulated and
> hyperpolluted present of the mid-22nd century. The series is based on
> an idea by British writer Kelly Marcel with Steven Spielberg as
> executive producer. On March 5, 2012, Fox announced that the show had
> been cancelled.

There's a [series trailer on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vhrQCkt1_c) that includes your big blue teleportation gate.

Comment: Nothing in the question says TV, so it shouldn't be tagged with it.

Comment: This was my first thought too, and I'm inclined to say it's almost certainly Terra Nova's Pilot episode.

Comment: Same thought here - the pilot episode was 85 minutes long (ie, short movie length), so could easily be mistaken for one!

Comment: This is reminiscent of the time travel from *[Saga of Pliocene Exile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile)* except fewer aliens.

Comment: I just watched the pilot episode of terra nova and I have to say Bro I don’t know who you are but you just answered a question I’ve been asking myself for almost a decade and thought I would never find. At some point I thought I Imagined all of that cause I couldn’t find the movie and it was driving me insane. I know it might seem like a small thing to you but it’s been bothering me for almost half my life and you just made my day. I guess I just wanna say thank you and I am very grateful.

Comment: Man, I wished they'd made season 2. Terra Nova was such a cool show!

Comment: I remember the first time I saw this show, I was 14 and it never went on TV here in Brazil, NEVER. I spent one entire week skipping the last class before lunch to get home in time to watch it

Comment: @Kevin Don't get attached to the show. It was cancelled, Firefly style.

Comment: @shearn89 Try "Lost in Space", the remake. I think you might like it.

Comment: @TurtleTail You as well.

Comment: @AndreKR I didn't know that was a thing. I'll sure try it, thx

Comment: Stop tagging ID questions with the answer.  That's not how we tag questions.